# App Scripts 403 Forbidden not been used in project error

Tags: google-apps-script

I am getting the following error with google app scripts.  My code was working a little while ago, but when I switched to another computer it broke everything.  Now I have no idea why it is showing the following error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Google Apps Script Execution API has not been used in project 608941808256 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/script/overview?project=608941808256 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Google Apps Script Execution API has not been used in project 608941808256 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/script/overview?project=608941808256 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

Trying to access my script that saves some data into a Google Sheet.  This project number does not even belong to me.  I have no idea where it is coming from or what it belongs to.

Anyone know what this error means?  If you need more info let me know and I can provide it

EDIT:

I figured out my problem.  In my android code I had a typo when setting the Application Name.  Once correcting this it was correctly linking to the correct project and everything worked again

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found this solution, adding two different flavours to the app:

```
productFlavors {
    prod {
        applicationId "tld.domain.appname"
    }
    demo {
        applicationId "tld.domain.appnamedebug"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the API to allow using this feature. Google allows a few times but it will block later. Have a look here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/enable-sdk

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this wasn't the problem.  If you read my question I said it was linking to another project that wasn't mine.  My project has the API enabled.  I figured out my problem though... had a type in the Application Name in my Android code.  Don't know how it worked before if it was using the same typo